Passing additional params to Next auth Google signIn
I was trying to add a field role on the user data object while signing up with Google or Github. Here is the provider portion's Google object:
Google({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!,
      profile(profile, tokens) {
        return {
          id: profile.sub,
          name: `${profile.given_name} ${profile.family_name}`,
          email: profile.email,
          role: profile.role ? profile.role : "User",
        };
      },
    }),

I'm expecting it to act like if the role is passed, then the value of role will be that specific string and the default value will be "User" if no value is passed for role. But I dont know how to set the role value with the signIn function as no parameter can be passed or retrieved through this function.
I tried to do this but that din't help
await signIn(
      "google",
      {
        callbackUrl: "/seller/dashboard",
        redirect: true,
      },
      { role: "Seller" }
    );

